# How to call JSONObject in Retrofit2 api calls?

Tags: android, json

Example: My input is

```
{
  "company_id": 1,
  "customer_id": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "service_id": "1",
      "service_description": "description here",
      "service_quantity": 1,
      "service_uom": "number",
      "service_price": "10000",
      "service_total": "10000",
      "service_taxid": 1,
      "service_taxvalue": "10"
    },
    {
      "service_id": "2",
      "service_description": "description here",
      "service_quantity": 1,
      "service_uom": "number",
      "service_price": "10000",
      "service_total": "10000",
      "service_taxid": 1,
      "service_taxvalue": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

I declared like: API Call-

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("URL")
Observable <SampleResponse> generateInvoice(@Field("company_id") Integer companyId, @Field("customer_id") Integer customer_id, @Field("items") JSONArray params);
```

Declaration:

```
JSONObject service1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    service1.put("service_id", id);
    service1.put("service_description", Desc);
    service1.put("service_quantity", Integer.valueOf(Qty));
    service1.put("service_uom", "number");
    service1.put("service_price", Amt);
    service1.put("service_total", GAmt);
    service1.put("service_taxid", 1);
    service1.put("service_taxvalue", 5);
    Log.d("jsonobject created", "" + service1);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONArray array = new JSONArray().put(service1);
presenter.generateInvoice(1,"company123",array);
```

> Error at backend: '{\"service_id\":3,\"service_description\":\"Mobile
>   Application\",\"service_quantity\":5,\"service_uom\":\"number\",\"service_price\":\"650\",\"service_total\":\"3640\",\"service_taxid\":1,\"service_taxvalue\":5}';

Slashes are not in api input call, but seen at backend. This results in http 500 error. I tried adding @Body RequestClass and removed @FormUrlEncoded, but that doesn't work since it has @Field. Or Do we need 2 api calls to achieve this?

Comment: Http 500 error is a problem related to your server, not your client code

Comment: You have to look at the error being sent incorrectly, or the server is mishandling and 500 errors drop.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved
For the given input, we should make a json object and post data using @Body RequestBody. No need to @Field. Below id the code to make one single json object which includes all data-

> 

```
JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject service1 = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        service1.put("service_id", id);
                        service1.put("service_description", Desc);
                        service1.put("service_quantity", Integer.valueOf(Qty));
                        service1.put("service_uom", "number");
                        service1.put("service_price", Amt);
                        service1.put("service_total", GAmt);
                        service1.put("service_taxid", 1);
                        service1.put("service_taxvalue", 5);

                        finalobject.put("company_id",companyid);
                        finalobject.put("customer_id",CUST_ID);
                        itemsArray.put(service1);
                        finalobject.put("items",itemsArray);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

finalobject will gives json object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your object to a JSONArray, Retrofit will do it automatically for you.

Simply change your API method declaration to:

```
Observable <SampleResponse> generateInvoice(@Body("company_id") Integer companyId, @Body("customer_id") Integer customer_id, @Body("items") List<Items> params);
```

Comment: Wrong declaration for @Body in api call

Comment: Try with Field instead of Body

Comment: No that doesn't come like in the above mentioned array(input)

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Can you describe it in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be worked

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        int i=0;
        while (YOUR_CONDITION)
        {
            JSONObject service1 = new JSONObject();
            try {
                service1.put("service_id", "id");
                service1.put("service_description", "Desc");
                service1.put("service_quantity","Qty");
                service1.put("service_uom", "number");
                service1.put("service_price", "Amt");
                service1.put("service_total", "GAmt");
                service1.put("service_taxid", 1);
                service1.put("service_taxvalue", 5);
                Log.d("jsonobject created", "" + service1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            array.put(service1);
            i++;
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("items",array);
            Log.d("value",object.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How could you put for JSONArray like that. its wrong statement

Comment: `'items' => '[2,\"Web Application\",5,\"number\",\"60\",\"315\",1,5]'
` it results like this in backend

Answer (score 0):

Make Api Service Call like below

Function that is used to Send User Order   Data to Server

```
@POST("api/customer/order/place")
Call<Order_Response_List> sendorderofconsumer(@Header("Authorization") String token,  @Body SendOrderList orderPost);
```

After This Make Class SendOrderList   like this

```
public class SendOrderList {


    @SerializedName("shipping_address_id")
    @Expose
    private String shippingAddressId;
    @SerializedName("billing_address_id")
    @Expose
    private String billingAddressId;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Check_out_delivery_temp_data_model> items = null;

    @SerializedName("delivery_time")
    @Expose
    private String delivery_time;


    public SendOrderList() {

    }


    public SendOrderList(String shippingAddressId, String billingAddressId, List<Check_out_delivery_temp_data_model> items, String delivery_time) {
        this.shippingAddressId = shippingAddressId;
        this.billingAddressId = billingAddressId;
        this.items = items;
        this.delivery_time = delivery_time;
    }

    public String getDelivery_time() {
        return delivery_time;
    }

    public void setDelivery_time(String delivery_time) {
        this.delivery_time = delivery_time;
    }

    public String getShippingAddressId() {
        return shippingAddressId;
    }

    public void setShippingAddressId(String shippingAddressId) {
        this.shippingAddressId = shippingAddressId;
    }

    public String getBillingAddressId() {
        return billingAddressId;
    }

    public void setBillingAddressId(String billingAddressId) {
        this.billingAddressId = billingAddressId;
    }

    public List<Check_out_delivery_temp_data_model> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Check_out_delivery_temp_data_model> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Then Set Data in this Class through set Function